# When using Express Router are these two lines equivalent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I could not find the official docs in a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=express%20router%20get&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS769US769&oq=express%20router%20get&aqs=chrome..69i57.2564j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  Where are the official API docs for express.Router() and are lines 1 and 2 the same?

If so, is it just a matter of preference on which to use?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('path', callback); // line 1
router.route('path').get(callback); // line 2
```

Comment: Docs: [router.route()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route) && [router.METHOD](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD) - descriptions should be self explanatory.

Comment: I just noticed you can use `app.get()` as well, is there a guide somewhere that let's you know when it is appropriate to use the 3+ options for handling a simple GET request?

Comment: There are probably like a 1000 Medium articles. It seems there just a few: 1) be as consistent as you can 2) use the feature your team is most familiar with 3) if you are duplicating a lot of logic for every route, use `router.route()`. Good luck.

Comment: They both serves the same purpose. The only difference is that with the latter one, you can chain the `http` request methods like `router.route("/user").get(fn).post(fn).delete(fn)` whereas in the first implementation you would be writing something like `router.get("/user", fn); router.post("/user", fn)`

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways with which you can declare routes in your application

These are:

1. `app.get("path", fn)`
2. `router.get("path", fn)`
3. `router.route("path").get(fn)`

All of the above functions are used to generate http request routes in your application.

The `app.get` is the most basic one and is not recommended for larger projects. The reason being it gives less flexibility in handling routes as compared to the `express.router`. In express applications you will be dealing with middlewares a lot. Middlewares are functions that are executed before the controller function of your application

For example, take a look at this line

`app.get("/user", verifyUser, createUser)`;`

Above, `verifyUser` is a middleware function that is called with `(Request, Response, Next) arguments by the express framework, you can write your incoming request verification logic in verifyUser and can then call`NextFunction`to pass the control to the next function with is the`createUser`controller`;

You can have as many middlewares as you want in your route declaration.

What if you need to call `verifyUser` each time a user is created, removed, fetched or modified. For each of the actions, you need to define your routes like this:

```js
  app.get("/user", verifyUser, fetchUser);
  app.put("/user", verifyUser, updateUser);
  app.post("/user", verifyUser, createUser);
  app.delete("/user", verifyUser, deleteUser);
```

In larger applications you need to defined different logics to different entities and routes.

`express.router` solves the above problem by providing us a flexibility to define what to do when user lands the `/user` route before passing the request to the middleware.

The above code in express router can be written as follows:

```js
  // file: userRoutes.js
  const router = express.Router();

  router.use((req, res, next) => {
     verifyUser(req, res, next);
  });

  function verifyUser(req, res, next) {
    // verification logic here
    if (/** verification is successful */)
      return next(); // return to the controller
    res.status(400).json({ msg: "user does not exists" });
  }

  router.get("/user", fetchUser);
  router.put("/user", updateUser);
  router.post("/user", createUser);
  router.delete("/user", deleteUser);

  module.exports = router;

  // app.js
  const userRoutes = require("./userRoutes");
  app.use(userRoutes);
```

Things gets really simplified if we chain the http request methods in the following way:

```
  router.route("/user")
        .get(fetchUser);
        .put(updateUser);
        .post(createUser);
        .delete(deleteUser);
```

Note: Above code is for explanation purpose only, there may be syntax errors, the code is not expected to run as it is. User might need to alter the code to make it work.